# Java update panel for all users upon database change

Tags: java, swing, postgresql, server

So I have a program that runs on multiple computers. The program connects to a server where it gets all of its data from. There's a JPanel which lists names from a table in my postgresql database. As of now, the only way to refresh the panel is with a button press. I want the panel to update on its own when there is a change in the database so if one user adds a name, the other users will be able to see the change right away. Is there a way to broadcast a message to all users that are connected to the server so that their panel can refresh?

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/listennotify.html)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yep, LISTEN and NOTIFY is the way to go here. However, please don't link to old documentation versions. Link to the current version or even better change the version like /80/ to /current/ in the URL

Comment: @CraigRinger Feel free to supply an updated link, it's just the first thing I hit when I did a google search

Comment: @MadProgrammer and Craig Thanks, that's just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want to do something like this you enter the world of multiple threads and all kinds of havock. Your question does not really have anything to do with databases, you merely want to send a message to all others using the application to update a component when they need to, keep your concerns separate. Now then you need to ask some questions like are the users all on the same network? Then you can get away with a simple chat client for java, there are heaps of them out there. But think about it, do you really need this requirement? Can't you just update the table say every 10 seconds? Or every 5 seconds? The difference in the difficulty of the implementation is substantial but the result I would say would be very similiar, unnoticable to the user even. But maybe you just want to learn stuff, then maybe you think you should add another table in sql with one entry which records the time the user table was updated which you can check and will be more optimal than the other. But this is considered bad practice, do you care? Same with sql statements to check when a table was edited last from what I have seen on the net, but should we always apply best practices, the application will still get across the line.

Maybe your update button is not looking so bad after all.

But users complain about that sort of crap and you can't explain this stuff to every user. My suggestion would be to have a configurable update that runs every how ever many seconds you tell it to. You will have to look up stuff about multi-threading though but shouldn't be too horrible.